# Documentation of cursor options for Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Can anyone direct me to thorough documentation of the draggableCursor object?  I see lots of short and sweet examples of implementation like
[How do i set a custom image for the mouse cursor in a google map api v3 map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652178/how-do-i-set-a-custom-image-for-the-mouse-cursor-in-a-google-map-api-v3-map)
or
[Google Maps API v3 draggableCursor options such as position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687213/google-maps-api-v3-draggablecursor-options-such-as-position)
but I'm not finding the info about the structure of the object, or links to good documentation with what the options like 'auto, move, crosshair' refer too.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same format as the css cursor values: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor

Not all browsers support all the values however.

Comment: thanks that's an important doc to know

Comment: It's also possible to use custom cursors. Same format as CSS, as Chad said.